# Does MSpec produce a TRX result file after running tests?

Tags: unit-testing, mspec, acceptance-testing

Does MSpec produce a [TRX result file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#resultsfile) after running tests?  If not, can it? The tests are being run with ReSharper.

Comment: Please clarify how MSTest is the engine, if you're running tests with ReSharper then isn't ReSharper the engine? What do you need the TRX file for?

Comment: From what I'm guessing, ReSharper just shells out the work to MSTest for test execution.  I believe if you kick off the tests from a command line, you will get some kind of output file.  It's not a TRX, but an output of some kind.  I'm looking for the equivalent when run within the IDE.

Comment: The results in the IDE are displayed in the ReSharper unit test session window. It's just a different window than the MSTest unit test session results.

Comment: @Atom Kawlness For what do you need the trx file? If you need it for TFS have a look at http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature of ReSharper that you're talking about is just a test *runner*. It can run tests from MSTest, NUnit, and other frameworks by using custom plugins. MSpec is a completely separate test *engine/framework*.

MSpec can [output](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications#readme) a number of reports: [TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity), [HTML](http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2009/08/26/step-by-step-to-using-machine-specifications-with-resharper/), and XML. I can't run MSpec to verify the XML output right now, but I did review the [XML report generator code](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/Source/Machine.Specifications.Reporting/Generation/Xml/XmlReportGenerator.cs). It appears to write the "concern | context | specification" report that you can see in the HTML example. And *not an MSTest TestResults file (.trx)*.

I don't see any way to output a TRX right now. You can submit an issue or write some kind of generator, but I don't know if it's worthwhile.

Comment: Any of the outputs that MSpec can do natively would also work.  I've seen that I can get these to output when I run MSpec tests from the console.  I'm trying to figure out how to get any of these from ReSharper's test runner.

Comment: ReSharper supports [exporting](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Sessions.html) a test run.

Comment: I've seen that.. and it's almost the solution I'm looking for.  That would work to solve the problem I'm trying to solve, but I need a way to make that happen automatically.

Comment: Don't produce reports from the Visual Studio run. Always run your reported runs from the command line.

Comment: I'm with you that it's not the ideal way to get your reports.  But this question is focused on that scenario.

Comment: My question does have an answer. "Does MSpec produce a TRX result file after running tests? If not, can it?"  Looks like the answer is no, it can not.